# Appending text to textfile getting weird characters?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

After successfully appending text to a text file, I'm getting weird characters, is it because I'm not setting the correct format? Here's the code I've tried:

```
Dim fso As Object
Dim Msg As string
Msg = "Hello World"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim Fileout As Object
Dim filePath As String
filePath = "C:\file.txt"
Const ForAppending = 8
Set Fileout = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, ForAppending) <<== might be the error not sure
Fileout.WriteBlankLines (1)
Fileout.Write Msg
Fileout.Close
Set fso = Nothing
Set Fileout = Nothing
```

Output:

Testing my appends.਍牅潲⁲‣ㄠ〰‴ <<<== getting that stuff on append.

Comment: what is the value of `filePath` and `ForAppending`?

Comment: check updated post. file path is c:\file.txt, ForAppending is 8

Comment: After appending, I open my text file to see what got append, what I see is the Chinese characters only. "This was what is in my textfile before appending" <<--- that is already in the text file.

Comment: No. the hello world does not show up, only the Chinese characters ect.

Comment: Oh, well it runs perfectly for me. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Did you already have text in the textfile before appending?

Comment: Yes, I did test with and without text.

Comment: @user590792 open your text file with notepad first, check encoding in Save As dialog, then set the same encoding in 4th argument of `.OpenTextFile` method (-2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII). I believe your file has Unicode encoding, so the 4th argument should be `-1`.

Comment: @omegastripes that solved it, my notepad was set to ANSCI or something, switch it over to UNICODE and boom, works. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would set the file format to 'Unicode' instead of the deafulat so that a Byte Order Mark (BOM) is written which other MS applications can use to recognise the file encoding

If your text is limited to ASCII I would also try that format.

I don't know what effect these have on the initial BOM when appending (probably none).

> object.OpenTextFile(filename[, iomode[, create[, format]]])
>
> The format argument can have any of the following settings:
>
> ```
> Constant           Value  Description
> TristateUseDefault    2   Opens the file using the system default.
> TristateTrue          1   Opens the file as Unicode.
> TristateFalse         0   Opens the file as ASCII.
> ```

[Visual Basic for Applications Reference - OpenTextFile Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx)

Note that "Unicode" is a Microsoft misnomer for the encoding UTF-16 LE. There are several different Unicode encodings. Arguably the most appropriate one, UTF-8, is not obviously explicitly specifiable in this API.

Comment: I've tried fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, 8, true, 2) but it is getting me that argument error.

Comment: Try telling it what the arguments are. Updating the KB reference

Answer (score 0):

open your text file with notepad first, check encoding in Save As dialog, then set the same encoding in 4th argument of .OpenTextFile method (-2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII). I believe your file has Unicode encoding, so the 4th argument should be -1.